# Error with elasticsearch_http Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to run this:

```
input {  
    twitter {
        # add your data
        consumer_key => "shhhhh"
        consumer_secret => "shhhhh"
        oauth_token => "shhhhh"
        oauth_token_secret => "shhhhh"
        keywords => ["words"]
        full_tweet => true
    }
}
output {  
    elasticsearch_http {
        host => "shhhhh"
        index => "idx_ls"
        index_type => "tweet_ls"
    }
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-02-24T04:48:03,060][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Problems loading a plugin with {:type=>"output", :name=>"elasticsearch_http", :path=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http", :error_message=>"NameError", :error_class=>NameError, :error_backtrace=>["/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:221:in `namespace_lookup'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:157:in `legacy_lookup'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:133:in `lookup'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:175:in `lookup_pipeline_plugin'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugin.rb:129:in `lookup'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:452:in `plugin'", "(eval):12:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1079:in `eval'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:98:in `initialize'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:246:in `create_pipeline'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:95:in `register_pipeline'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:264:in `execute'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:183:in `run'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.2.1/libexec/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}
[2017-02-24T04:48:03,073][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {  \n    twitter {\n        # add your data\n        consumer_key => \"shhhhh\"\n        consumer_secret => \"Shhhhhh\"\n        oauth_token => \"shhhh\"\n        oauth_token_secret => \"shhhhh\"\n        keywords => [\"word\"]\n        full_tweet => true\n    }\n}\noutput {  \n    elasticsearch_http {\n        host => \"shhhhh.amazonaws.com\"\n        index => \"idx_ls\"\n        index_type => \"tweet_ls\"\n    }\n}\n", :reason=>"Couldn't find any output plugin named 'elasticsearch_http'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the elasticsearch_http output plugin resulted in this error: Problems loading the requested plugin named elasticsearch_http of type output. Error: NameError NameError"}
```

I've tried installing `elasticsearch_http` but it doesnt seem to be a package. Ive also tried

logstash-plugin install logstash-input-elasticsearch
and
logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch

which did install but got the same error.

Totally new to logstash so this might be very simple.
I am Trying to follow this https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/08/three-easy-ways-to-stream-twitter-data-into-elasticsearch/

I tried Val's answer and got this:

```
[2017-02-24T05:12:45,385][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>#<URI::HTTP:0x4c2332e0 URL:http://shhhhh:9200/>, :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://sshhhhhh:9200/][Manticore::ConnectTimeout] connect timed out"}
```

I can go to the url and i get a response on browser and I it set open on permissions so Im not sure what the issue with that would be.

Answer (score 1):

The `elasticsearch_http` output is no longer alive. You need to use the `elasticsearch` output instead.

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "idx_ls"
    document_type => "tweet_ls"
}
```

Comment: tried and it didnt work. please see my update, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had copy/pasted the wrong plugin name, please try again

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @Val's answer. What if you have your `hosts` parameter without the port:

```
output {        
        elasticsearch {         
            index => "idx_ls"
            document_type => "tweet_ls"
            hosts => "localhost"            
        }
}
```

by default ES runs on port *9200* so you don't have to explicitly set it up.

Comment: if you don't specify the port, it'll take 80 by default

Comment: @Val Oh I thought ES normally runs on 9200. Saw it here [too](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html#_restful_api_with_json_over_http)

Comment: @Bren if you could post the whole error? And what if you try it with another port which is not in the range of *9200-9300*? still the same?

Comment: ES runs on 9200, but if you don't specify the port, the default port is 80 as far as the HTTP client library is concerned.